# Can't run Netbeans or Eclipse, but can compile Java applications manually

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk, openjdk, netbeans

Like the title states, I can't run Netbeans or Eclipse. When I run Netbeans, I get what looks like the outline of the splash screen, then nothing. When I run Eclipse, I get this error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.8.1.dist/splash.bmp
-launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins /   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist/eclipse_1503.so
-startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins      /org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 250007
-clean
-initialize
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
```

My java installation:

```
java -version

openjdk version "9-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)
```

What's most odd to me is that I can compile and run a simple program just fine using the command line tools provided.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling for openJDK, netbeans, and eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using JDK 9 which is still in development. Some command-line arguments/features from earlier JDKs are not (currently) present in Java 9. Try downgrading to JDK 8.

<sup>P.S.: Have you tried IntelliJ? It's my personal preference for an IDE.</sup>

Comment: This would really be better suited as a comment.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I uninstalled JDK 9 and set 8 as my current version.


And yes, I've tried it. I use Webstorm at work pretty frequently and like it. There's a few reason I can't use IntelliJ for this though. I need Java EE, don't want to pay, and it's for a school group project so I can't really ask others to pay either. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Comment: @lgh You can send in a picture of your School ID and get IntelliJ U free for a year! :D

Comment: I've already used that up. It was a sweet, luxurious year.

Comment: You can renew it with the new ID